# Can we side load an outlook add-in by clicking button of another outlook add-In? I mean can we load an add-In using another add-In?

Tags: load, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins

```
const loadSecondaryAddin = () => {
window.location.href = "lINK";
```

};

```
return (
    <> 
        <DocumentCard className={subDocumentCard ? styles.sub_card : styles.main_card } onClick={loadSecondaryAddin}>
```

This didn't worked. The Linked add-in's loading page is loading. But data are not loading. How to fix this.

This didn't worked. The Linked add-in's loading page is loading. But data are not loading. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not support opening a second add-in from a running add-in at this time.We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.
If your case can be solved by opening a dialog instead of a new add-in then you can look through this tutorial -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins .